# How to copy one DataFrame column in to another Dataframe if their indexes values are the same

Tags: python, pandas

After creating a DataFrame with some duplicated cell values in column with the name 'keys':

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'keys': [1,2,2,3,3,3,3],'values':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

[image]

I go ahead and create two more DataFrames which are the consolidated versions of the original DataFrame `df`. Those newly created DataFrames will have no duplicated cell values under the 'keys' column:

```
df_sum = df_a.groupby('keys', axis=0).sum().reset_index()
df_mean = df_b.groupby('keys', axis=0).mean().reset_index()
```

As you can see `df_sum['values']` cells values were all summed together.
While `df_mean['values']` cell values were averaged with `mean()` method.
Lastly I rename the 'values' column in both dataframes with:

```
df_sum.columns = ['keys', 'sums']
df_mean.columns = ['keys', 'means']
```

[image]

Now I would like to copy the `df_mean['means']` column into the dataframe `df_sum`.

How to achieve this?

The Photoshoped image below illustrates the dataframe I would like to create. Both 'sums' and 'means' columns are merged into a single DataFrame:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `pandas.merge()` is the function you are looking for. Like `pd.merge(df_sum, df_mean, on = "keys")`. Besides, this result can also be summarized on one `agg` function as following:

```
df.groupby('keys')['values'].agg(['sum', 'mean']).reset_index()
#  keys sum mean
#0    1   1  1.0
#1    2   5  2.5
#2    3  22  5.5
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this.  Using the `merge` function off the dataframe is the most efficient.

```
df_both = df_sum.merge(df_mean, how='left', on='keys')

df_both

Out[1]:
   keys  sums  means
0     1     1    1.0
1     2     5    2.5
2     3    22    5.5
```